# Upload zip file by Nusoap in PHP and C#

Tags: c#, web-services, nusoap

I want to upload file with C# client app and Nusoap webservice. How i can do this? I use Nusoap webservice for insert in database but for upload files i don't have any idea. Please help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I haven't any experience with NuSOAP, I shall answer with the best of my knowledge of uploading a file to a server running PHP, without using NuSOAP.

The following code will `POST` the contents of a given file to a PHP page, as if it was sent via a standard HTML form.

```
public void UploadFile(string path) {
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    Int64 numBytes = new FileInfo(path).Length;
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
    Byte[] data = br.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(numBytes));
    br.Close();
    fs.Close();
    wc.UploadData("http://127.0.0.1/upload.php", "POST", data);
}
```

Edit: Here is the PHP that I used for this a while ago. It is potentially insecure and will always overwrite the *same* file every time a new one is being uploaded. You could try to work some dynamic-ness into this, along with some file checks for security sake... but you should also be able to use a modified PHP file intended for standard uploads (from a web form).

```
<?php
    $fp = fopen('snap.jpg', 'wb');
    fwrite($fp, file_get_contents('php://input'));
    fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: Hi and thanks about your answer. But whats content of upload.php? Is it similar to any upload form or not?

Comment: Can you help me about uploading file in PHP ?

Comment: Sorry, I was sleeping. I have edited my answer with the PHP that I used to store the file. Note that there are securer and better ways of doing this.